# Angular UI router animate nested view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have been trying to work out how to animate just a nested a view using ui-router. But all attempts have failed. What I am trying to do is just fade in the nested view called `body` I don't want to animate the header. I have made this example as small as possible. I recognize that if restructured my code to not be nested I would not have this issue but in production I need to have this nested.

here is my `scss` and html.

```
#mainView.ng-enter {

  .nested-view-animate {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  }
}

#mainView.ng-enter-active {

  .nested-view-animate {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  }
}

#mainView.ng-leave {

  .nested-view-animate {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  }
}

#mainView.ng-leave-active {

  .nested-view-animate {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  }
}
```

This is my html

```
<div ui-view id="mainView">

   <!-- below is what is included dynamically -->
  <div>

    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <!-- I want to animate when the content in here is loaded-->
    <div ui-view="body" class="nested-view-animate"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Again all I am trying to do is fade in new content into the "body" and fade out the old stuff.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in Plunker?